# Правильное использование шаблонного объекта c шаблонном методом в методе шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, методы

При создании шаблонного объекта с шаблонном методом в методе шаблонного класса, с параметром класса возникает ошибка. При этом если указать в качестве параметра объекта явно тип (не параметр класса), то все нормально. Почему так происходит?
Исходный код:

```
#include <iostream>

template< class N >
class A {       
    public:
        template< class M >
        void fun(N n, M m) {
            std::cout << "Hello World! " << n << " " << m << std::endl;
        }
};

template< class N, class M >
class B {
    public:
        void fun(N n, M m) {
        A< N > a;   // Почему если здесь вместо N написать int, то все нормально, а если как есть то ошибка?
        a.fun< M >(n, m);
    }
};

int main() {
    B< int, int > b;
    b.fun(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка при компиляции:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void B<N, M>::fun(N, M)’:
main.cpp:28:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  a.fun< M >(n, m);
```

С уважением, Александр

Comment: Вызывать нужно вот так `a.fun(n, m);`

Comment: Не могу найти шаблонный объект....

Answer (score 3):

Да не указывайте ничего :), компилятор сам все выведет:

```
void fun(N n, M m) {
    A< N > a;
    a.fun(n, m);
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/PMMgXP

И, кстати, метка "шаблоны", если вы читали описание, относится к шаблонам проектирования.

Answer (score 2):

Надо искользовать ключевое слово `template`, чтобы уверить компилятор, что мы вызываем шаблонную функцию:

```
a.template fun<M>(n, m);
```

Аналогично тому, как мы указываем шаблонный тип с помощью `typename` для зависимых типов:

```
typename DependantType<T>::type x;
```

вместо:

```
DependantType<T>::type x;
```